# Prestashop 1.6 - Several order confirmation emails instead of one

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using Prestashop 1.6, and I encounter a problem with the admin confirmation emails (MailAlerts) and the order confirmation emails sent to the users.

If a customer buy products that use different carrier each, an email for each carrier will be sent. But I need my Prestashop to send only one email that groups the whole order. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

When an order is placed with products that use different carrier then the order is actually split into multiple orders (with reference number #1, #2 etc at the end), you can check the same by viewing the orders list after placing any such order. This is the reason why multiple order emails are sent.

The multiple orders that are generated have multiple order IDs as well so it is not feasible to send a single email for such orders.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I guess it's not feasable to merge the orders in one either ?